# Inject value in another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am developing a system that has a list of elements and when you choose one, you see the details of that element. I am using MEAN. What I am trying to do is pass the id of the element selected to the controller of the second page. I was trying to achieve this by using value and services but it is giving me this error:

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: chooserIdProvider <- chooserId <- controllerIdService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/unpr?p0=chooserIdProvider[object Object]3C-%6chooserId%6%3C-%6controllerIdService
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js:116
```

This is my code(I will only show the part of the service and value): 
firstController:

```
var streamingApp = angular.module('streaming', ['ngRoute']);

streamingApp.controller("homeController", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    ...

    $scope.process = function(chooserId) {
        streamingApp.value('chooserId', chooserId);
        $location.path("/indico")
    }
```

firstWeb (the part where $scope.process is used):

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="process(chooser._id)">Process</a>
```

secondController:

```
streamingApp.service('controllerIdService', ['chooserId', function(chooserId) {
    this.chooserId = chooserId;
}]);

streamingApp.controller("indicoController", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'controllerIdService', function ($scope, $http, $location, controllerIdService) {
    this.chooserId = chooserId;
```

secondWeb:

```
    <h5>{{chooserId}}</h5>
```

Comment: where do you get chooserId From? post the code

Comment: I get it from an ng-repeat in the part of the first web, that works

Comment: no that should be a constant

Answer (score 0):

You should access the variable like this:  `controllerIdService.chooserId`. And also it should be present in the scope for accessing it in the view.